# What is best strategy to group servers in Azure Deployment Groups

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have 4 target env Dev,QA,UAT and PROD
Each envs has 3 Azure VM , Web , API and Database
Should I Create

1. 4 Deployment Groups Dev, QA, UAT and PROD and Add 3 targets in each of these 4 deployement groups and Tag those targets as Web, API and Database ?
2. Or Create 3 Deployment Groups Web , API and Database and add 4 targets in each group and tag is as Dev,QA,UAT and PROD ?
3. Or create 4 Environments (Dev,QA,UAT and PROD ) and add 3 resources in every env.

Note :

1. Not to mention , every env will have different connection-strings
2. If I already added one VM as a target in deployment group , I can not add it as a resource in environment
3. I want to use same release pipeline to deploy to Dev --> QA --> UAT --> PROD in stages with approval. Basically build once and deploy to multiple envs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use environments with the classic release pipelines. So option 3 is out. However the described option would be valid if you used YAML pipelines to deploy your application.

Out of options 1 and 2, You should the first one because it has less room for errors and the production environment is better protected. You could also use 12 groups (one for each combination), but the additional effort is probably not worth it.

This would also follow the [Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).

> Deployment groups represent the physical environments; for example, "Dev", "Test", or "Production" environment.
>
> [...]
>
> Enable you to use machine tags to limit deployment to specific sets of target servers.

Comment: Thanks , But I had already checked that post

Comment: @Sagar good to hear. Do you have any more questions on the matter? I believe the clear favorite is option "1" unless you want to create 12 deployment groups (one for each combination)